# Is Filewatcher considered non blocking IO in Java?

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

This is the code snippet from FileWatcher java 7 nio library.
Is it non blocking code? This threads waits for the signal from FileSystem.

```
for (;;) {
    // wait for key to be signaled
    WatchKey key;
    try {
        key = watcher.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it runs in a thread separate from the process you are concerned about, then it is non-blocking with respect to the other code. A sample of code from inside a thread is not non-blocking

Comment: @cricket_007: That's not what non-blocking means.  And that has nothing to do with IO.

Comment: Non-blocking in this context means that the user thread that initiated the I/O does not pause until the I/O is completed.  At some lower level there is going to be a thread whose job it is to handle I/O interrupts and figure out what to do with them based on a table of currently pending requests.  After that thread handles all current interrupts it will block until the next I/O interrupt.  But you have no access to that thread, it is independent of user code.  Depending on how NIO is implemented that thread could be Java or in the operating system.

Comment: Out of context it is difficult to say, but the code seems to be using a `WatchService`.  In that case, yes, execution may block in `watcher.take()`, but only in the event that *none* of the I/O units being watched is ready.  In such context, this code is non-blocking in the sense that an I/O unit that is ready will not go unserviced while control is blocked trying to perform I/O on a unit that is unready.

Comment: @John Bollinger , here WatchKey initial state is ready and is blocked. In case of I/O events, key is signalled. Then kind of events can be identified and WatchKey has to be reset again to ready state for I/O events again. The whole process looks synchronous

Comment: Who said it is non-blocking code in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filewatcher uses `EPOLL` which is a Linux system call. It's a multiplexing mechanism which is event based. For Windows there is `SELECT` which does the same thing, but far less efficient and in BSD (which OSX is based on) there is `KQUEUE`.

In simple terms what it does is it registers an event handler in the system that is waiting for an event to occur. As time progresses the system takes a look at all the queued event handlers and sees if there is one that is ready to proceed. If there is a event handler that has it's event flag set to true then it will handle that event. If there is no events it will keep looping until it finds an event that occurred.

In the meantime the code in main continues to run, thus giving you the "non-blocking" functionality in which it promises.

This isn't new technology, although ASYNC has become quite popular recently with the rise of NodeJS, Swift and other non-blocking languages / frameworks this same sort of thing is how the WIN32 API works - in short it's all event based.

You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845634/general-explanation-of-how-epoll-works) for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: wait and signalling process in the above snippet is synchronous. "take" method waits for I/O Event and the initial state of WatchKey is ready until it is signaled by the event handling system. Again , WatchKey has to be reset back to ready state. This code has to be in infinite loop to watch for the folder/file events. To save main thread, Watcher service need to be created in seperate user thread.